# merge the dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I given the sample of data-frame

```
  Name value  A   Msg_A       Invalid_A     Msg_B   Invalid_B       Msg_C        Invalid_C 

0  j    3     A  Not VAid XYZ   True        VAlid       False     Not Valid_c     True   
1  B    4     B  VAid ABC       False       notVAlidb   TRue      Not Valid_c     True
```

i want df like this

```
   Name value A    Msg_A      Invalid_A   Msg_B    Invalid_B       Msg_C     Invalid_C  Message

0  J     3    A  Not VAid XYZ   True     VAlid       False     Not Valid_c     True  Not VAid XYZ,Not Valid_c    
1  B     4    B  VAid ABC      False     notVAlidb   TRue      Not Valid_c     True   notVAlidb,Not Valid_c
```

i want to merge the msg_ in message column in if invalid column contains `True`

shape : `print(df.filter(like='Invalid_').values[:,None].shape)` --> (4, 1, 8)
i try with

```
df['message']=(df.filter(like='Status_')
 .where(df.filter(like='Invalid_').values[:,None].reshape(4,8))
 .apply(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna()),1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for reshape, then filter rows if `Invalid` is `True` and last aggregate `join`:

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                      stubnames=['Msg','Invalid'], 
                      sep='_', 
                      suffix='\w+', 
                      i=['index','Name','value','A'], 
                      j='tmp')
         .reset_index())

df1 = df1[df1['Invalid']]

df['message'] = df1.groupby('index')['Msg'].agg(', '.join)
print (df)
  Name  value  A         Msg_A  Invalid_A      Msg_B  Invalid_B        Msg_C  \
0    j      3  A  Not VAid XYZ       True      VAlid      False  Not Valid_c   
1    B      4  B      VAid ABC      False  notVAlidb       True  Not Valid_c   

   Invalid_C                    message  
0       True  Not VAid XYZ, Not Valid_c  
1       True     notVAlidb, Not Valid_c
```

Yopu can generate all columns not starting by `Msg` or `Invalid` to parameter `i`:

```
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.startswith(('Msg','Invalid'))].tolist()
                                
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                      stubnames=['Msg','Invalid'], 
                      sep='_', 
                      suffix='\w+', 
                      i=['index'] + cols, 
                      j='tmp')
         .reset_index())

df1 = df1[df1['Invalid']]

df['message'] = df1.groupby('index')['Msg'].agg(', '.join)
```

Your solution:

There is necessary same number of columns between both `df1` and `df2`, so possible set `df2.columns` by `df1.columns`:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Msg_')
df2 = df.filter(like='Invalid_')
#set columnsnames
df2.columns = df1.columns

df['message'] = df1.where(df2).apply(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna()),1)
print (df)
  Name  value  A         Msg_A  Invalid_A      Msg_B  Invalid_B        Msg_C  \
0    j      3  A  Not VAid XYZ       True      VAlid      False  Not Valid_c   
1    B      4  B      VAid ABC      False  notVAlidb       True  Not Valid_c   

   Invalid_C                   message  
0       True  Not VAid XYZ,Not Valid_c  
1       True     notVAlidb,Not Valid_c
```

Comment: i have total 74 column so how to use i=['index','Name','value','A'],  ??

Comment: @user14784453 - You think `74` columns before `Msg_A  Invalid_A` ?

Comment: No i have total 74 column and before Msg_A  Invalid_A i have 59 column

Comment: @user14784453 - If check second solution working?

Comment: @user14784453 - Super, added solution also for first one.